# how to replace ASCII characters other than 1-127 range in Google bigquery?

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

I have a requirement in which I wanted to replace characters other than ASCII character range 1-127.

Below is the oracle implementation:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(Student_Address, '[^' || CHR(1) || '-' || CHR(127) || ']','')
```

Could you please provide Bigquery equivalent solution.

Comment: I'm curious how you got them in there.  Everytime I try to push extended ascii, I get told no.

Comment: @arcee123 - who told you "no"? BigQuery supports Unicode, emojis, ...

Comment: Can we have a sample input and output to proceed, LAHU?

Comment: during bq load.  i always get error ansii code causes bad import failure.  So I deal with it in source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use below

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(Student_Address, r'[^[:ascii:]]', '')
```